# Having trouble running installing an MSI file using the batch command

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I have created the following batch file based on the recommendation Stein Åsmul.
Here's the link: [Batch script to install MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229460/batch-script-to-install-msi)
When I run the batch file the program the .msi file does not install and instead .msi file gets deleted from within the folder.

A copy of my batch file code, pretty simple:

```
echo.
Echo Installing EZL Consumer IDM 3.12.0036 now.
msiexec.exe/i c:\InstallationFiles\EZL\EZL3.12.0036InstallPrePackaged\
EasyLenderConsumerIDM3.12.0036Update3.msi 
/QN /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log
echo Installation complete.
```

attached copy of msilog.log

```
=== Verbose logging started: 12/01/2014  9:33:23  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  
Calling   process: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:232]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:232]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:232]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product:   
c:\InstallationFiles\EZL\EZL3.12.0036InstallPrePackaged\EasyLenderConsumerIDM3.12.0036Update3.msi
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:233]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on  
the server.
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:233]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI **strong text**(c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:366]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:366]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling   
Install on Server
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:394]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after  
increment: 0
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:402]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction  
c:\InstallationFiles\EZL\EZL3.12.0036InstallPrePackaged\EasyLenderConsumerIDM3.12.0036Update3.msi
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:402]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (8C:F4) [09:33:23:404]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (8C:F4) [09:33:23:404]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (8C:F4) [09:33:23:404]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product:   
c:\InstallationFiles\EZL\EZL3.12.0036InstallPrePackaged\EasyLenderConsumerIDM3.12.0036Update3.msi
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (8C:F4) [09:33:23:405]: Note: 1: 2203 2:   
c:\InstallationFiles\EZL\EZL3.12.0036InstallPrePackaged\
EasyLenderConsumerIDM3.12.0036Update3.msi  
3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (8C:F4) [09:33:23:405]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:406]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:406]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:406]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after  
increment: 0
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:406]: Note: 1: 1402 2:   
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:406]: Note: 1: 1402 2:   
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:407]: Note: 1: 1402 2:   
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:407]: Note: 1: 1402 2:  
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:407]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0,  
shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (8C:CC) [09:33:23:407]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:408]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, 
shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (DC:80) [09:33:23:409]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
=== Verbose logging stopped: 12/01/2014  9:33:23
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed back in the day? I think this is an MSI that runs nested MSI files as part of its main installation - essentially MSI files embedded in the original MSI run via custom actions. This is a deprecated feature of Windows Installer and can cause a number of strange problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\User>net helpmsg 3

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

or

```
 -2147287037 = 80030003
```

8003 is structured storage

```
0x80030003  STG_E_PATHNOTFOUND  The path %1 could not be found.
```

Comment: Is this your package or a 3rd party? MSI packages can store the file payload internally as a CAB filestream inside the package, externally as a cab file, or the payload can sit as raw files in a folder structure under the MSI (an Administrative Image). Does the installer work OK if you run it interactively? I wonder whether maybe you have been given the MSI file but the payload has somehow become decoupled from the file. Try doing an 'administrative' install of the MSI package (using /a rather than /i) and see what happens.