# How to set check boxes during msi installation using powershell?

Tags: checkbox, installation, powershell-3.0

I am trying to install a .msi file using powershell. But I cannot find a way to  in set check boxes while installation. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Typical powershell installation script steps:

```
1.Invoke-Item ‘C:\Script\somefile.exe’
```

Run given app (also .msi).

```
2.Select-Window PROCESS-NAME | Set-WindowActive
```

Set focus on the installer window, so you are able to send simulated keys to the installer.

```
3.Select-window PROCESS-NAME | Send-Keys “{ENTER}” | Send-Click
```

confirms given screen.

```
4.Select-window PROCESS-NAME | Send-Keys “{TAB}” | Send-Click
```

switches tabs in a given window.

```
5.Select-window PROCESS-NAME | Send-Keys ” ” | Send-Click
```

activates/deactivates active option button.

```
6.Select-Window PROCESS-NAME | Select-control| Send-Keys “123456789 1234” | Send-Click
```

gives you the method to fill textboxes.

```
7.Select-window PROCESS-NAME | Select-control | select-control -title “CHECK-BOX NAME” | Send-Click
```

**The part which you are interested in is point 7. You need to know the checkbox name and then you can send click command to it**.

[Microsoft reference site.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Will this method works in case of silent installation?

Comment: You should look at this answer for the answer of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25230485/210971